# Start a PowerShell script from C# on Windows Universal Platform IoT-Core

Tags: powershell, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

System.Management.Automation does not appear to exist for Windows 10 UWP (IoT-Core) and niether does the simple "new Process(); process.StartInfo..." command. How can I start a local PowerShell script from a IoT-Core C# app? Hacks welcome :-)

Comment: See [the IoT ProcessLauncher sample](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/ProcessLauncherSample.htm)

Comment: Hi Raymond. Works except for one thing, the argument that is passed as second parameter never gets seen if  I use a shell.cmd script as my first (command) argument. The shell.cmd script gets called, but no arguments present. What do I need to change? Thanks!

Comment: Archived [Sample Link](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/ExternalProcessLauncher/CS)